# Can a computer be vulnerable to BroadPwn?

Tags: wireless, known-vulnerabilities

There is a lot of info and warnings about most phones using Broadcom BCM43xx WiFi chipset that are vulnerable to remote code execution and full takeover.

What about computers? I saw that MacOS also got an security fix, but never heard anything about other brands. Many computers also have the very same chipset series.

Comment: "On laptops and desktop computers, the WiFi chipset generally handles the PHY layer while the kernel driver is responsible for handling layer 3 and above. " https://blog.exodusintel.com/2017/07/26/broadpwn/

Comment: That was my top search hit for your question title (after this question)